# C++ finding n points as close as possible to given xy

Tags: c++, algorithm, points

In RTS games, when you move some units, they find path and go to the places that are the closest to the selected place. I dont know how to select those places, I mean the target points for each unit.

For example, when I send 9 troops, I want them to have TARGETS like this:

```
. - empty, 
T - targets for units, 
O - the place that I've choosen to move them, target for unit too
.....
.TTT.
.TOT.
.TTT.
.....
```

Pathfinding algorithm is ready, just I need to generate the list (or vector) of target points, one for each unit. I dont want the complete code, but just some advices and ideas... Well I have to mind that not all places are walkable...

Thanx for any replies and sorry for my bad english...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) from the allocated point. "Fill" the selected tile with a unit if it is a tile that can hold a unit [not an obstacle]. Keep doing it until you "exhausted" the number of units.

In pseudo-code:

```
selectTargetLocation(point,units):
  currUnit <- 0
  queue<- new queue
  visited <- {}
  map<unit,point> <- empty map
  queue.push(point)
  while (queue.empty() == false): 
     current <- queue.takeFirst()
     visited.add(current)
     for each p such that p and current are neighbors: //insert neighbors to queue
          if p is not in visited: 
                queue.push(p)
     if current is not an obstacle: 
         map.put(unit[currUnit++],current) 
     if (currUnit == units.length) break //break when exhausted all units
  return map
```

Answer (score 1):

My idea would be like this: first, test if the destination is occupied, or a unit already has that destination. If this is the case, than you need to find a close point that is free. You could push all the near points to a queue, of the current point and so on... similar to fill algorithm), until you find a point that is not occupied. Then, find a path to that location.

Comment: This is exactly a BFS, except you do not maintain a `visted` set, which can lead to (1) over computation [you will compute too many times the same points]. (2) You might end up placing 2 units in the same tile

Comment: @amit Hm, After reading some articles about BFS, I've understood ur right :D Wikipedia article is complicated (with graphs, not map) so I thought, its not same :D

Comment: Fill is a BFS algorithm, so yeah, it is BFS... However, I prefer to think of BFS in a graph, not a multidimensional grid. There is an algorithm called Lee which is also very similar to BFS, used for shortest path searching in a grid.

Comment: Wait, got an idea. If I'd just send them to one place, And if the place is occupied, just stop where you are?

Comment: @kittyPL: It will result in overcomputation, you will have to compute the same thing `n` times [where `n` is the number of units sent]. Usually in RTS games [AFAIK] performance is an issue.

Comment: Or not... They are standing in line :/

Comment: so what? Maybe count one road for all, just change the ending?

Comment: It is kind of complicated... you need to have some sort of collision checking while it is moving, and if there is a collision, find another path. Your idea would overcomplicate the collision system.

Comment: I have collision checking :D If you are running windows I can send binaries if neede, you can check it then...

Comment: No need to... I'm working on a strategy game project too, I can't wait to get my graphics working, so I could work on these things :D

Comment: Can you show me your work? I dont need code, just to see how are your things going :D Im very proud of my penisula map generator :)

Comment: It's not much at the moment, just a png texture reader using libpng, some base classes for units, and some opengl stuff. So proud of myself right now, because finally the png textures work :D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8138/discussion-between-kittypl-and-tibi)